# Python pip still not recognized

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I've been trying to get pip to work with python. I've followed a lot of the guides out there and I still can't seem to get this working.
I've downloaded the file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.
I used the terminal to navigate to it and install.
When I go to settings in my project and look under 'interpreter' it shows that the pip package is definitely installed.
However, I still get the same message whenever I try to use the pip command

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

At line:1 char:1

- pip install dpkt
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I don't know what I'm missing here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand what the PATH environment variable is? Do you see *the folder for your Python installation* on the PATH?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run `pip` from PowerShell, I assume this is the PowerShell terminal inside PyCharm, given that you tagged the question PyCharm. Does the active virtual environment have pip? Do you even have a virtual environment (interpreter) assigned to the project in PyCharm?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there's no need for Python to be on the path when running Python through PyCharm, unless OP actually wants Python to be globally available and is looking to run / test their script in that environment. However, given that they are asking the question, it seems more likely that they are not familiar with Python environments in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `python -m pip install package-name`